# Join with Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join, inner-join, right-join

I am getting a syntax error with the following problem and can't seem to figure out, hope you guys can help me!

I have these tables (they are populated):

[image]

I am trying to retrieve the first and last name of all the passengers scheduled in a certain flight number so what I have is this:

```
SELECT PassFName, PassLName
FROM Passenger
INNER JOIN PassID ON Passenger.PassID = Reservation.PassID
INNER JOIN FlightNum ON FlightNum.Reservation = FlightNum.ScheduledFlight
WHERE ScheduledFlight.FlightNum = [Enter Flight Number];
```

However, I am getting error:

[image]

Not sure why and I have also noticed in the last line it is misspelling FlightNum.ScheduledFlight. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gordon's point is valid, but he's got his parentheses misplaced and missed the other big issues. This query is more than a little whacked, with table names and field names flip-flopped. Here's what I would guess would work...

```
SELECT
       PassFName
     , PassLName
FROM (
     Passenger
     INNER JOIN Reservation
        ON Passenger.PassID = Reservation.PassID
     )
INNER JOIN ScheduledFlight
    ON Reservation.FlightNum = ScheduledFlight.FlightNum
WHERE
     ScheduledFlight.FlightNum = [Enter Flight Number];
```

Answer (score 1):

MS Access has a strange syntax for joins.  It requires parentheses around each `JOIN` pair.  So:

```
SELECT PassFName, PassLName
FROM (Passenger INNER JOIN
      Reservation
     ) ON Passenger.PassID = Reservation.PassID INNER JOIN
     FlightNum
     ON FlightNum.Reservation = FlightNum.ScheduledFlight
WHERE ScheduledFlight.FlightNum = [Enter Flight Number];
```

Although other databases support this syntax, it is only required in MS Access.

Comment: I really don't know how to reply with a good format so it can be readable but here's the new error I am getting with that syntax:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8Hzx.jpg

Comment: @SPedraza . . . Presumably, you want `Reservation` as the second table, not `PassId`.

Comment: Do you mean Reservation as the first INNER JOIN? Why's that?

Comment: @SPedraza . . . There is no table called `PassId` as in your code example.

Comment: PassID is a PK in the Passenger and Reservation tables. I need it to get the first and last name and connect it to the ScheduledFlight table. Reservation is a lookup table.